# lagrangian relaxation - relaxing multiple constraints - linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier, constraints, relaxations

I am having problem understanding how to relax multiple constrains in linear programming. I know how to relax just one constrain of LP, but I have problem understanding how to constrain for example, two or three constrains.

Can someone show me how would objective function look like on this example:

\begin{align}
\min \ \sum\limits_{1 \leq k \leq K}&\sum\limits_{(i,j)\in E} c_{ij}x_{ij}^k \label{11}\\
\sum\limits_{1\leq k\leq K}x_{ij}^k & = y_{ij} \label{22}\\
\sum\limits_{1\leq j\leq n}y_{ij} &= 1, \ \forall i = 2, ..., n  \label{33} \\
\sum\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}y_{ij} &= 1, \ \forall j = 2, ..., n  \label{44}\\
\sum\limits_{1\leq j\leq n}y_{1j} &= K \label{55}\\
\sum\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}y_{i1} &= K \label{66}\\
\sum\limits_{2\leq i \leq n}\sum\limits_{1\leq j \leq n} d_ix_{ij}^k &\leq u, \ \forall k=1,2,...,K \label{77}\\
\sum\limits_{i \in Q}\sum\limits_{j \in Q} y_{ij}& \leq |Q|-1, \ \forall Q \subset \{2,...,n\} \label{88} \\
y_{ij} = 0 \ \text{or}& \ 1,\ \forall (i,j) \in E  \label{99}\\
x_{ij}^k = 0 \ \text{or}& \ 1,\ \forall (i,j)\in E, \ \forall k=1,2,...,K \label{1010}
\end{align}

So for example if we relax constrains $\sum\limits_{1\leq j\leq n}y_{ij} = 1, \ \forall i = 1, 2, ..., n $

$\sum\limits_{2\leq i \leq n}\sum\limits_{1\leq j \leq n} d_ix_{ij}^k \leq u, \ \forall k=1,2,...,K$

and

$\sum\limits_{i \in Q}\sum\limits_{j \in Q} y_{ij} \leq |Q|-1, \ \forall Q \subset \{2,...,n\}  $

we are left with assignment problem which is easy to solve. Can anyone show me how would objective function look like after relaxing these contrains?

This program is known as vehicle routing.

Thank youu

Comment: I dont understand quite well your problem, as the index $k$ appears to be a power??. Or this is just another ranging index??

Comment: Besides, you have a contradiction in the $=K$ constraints, following the $=1$ constraints... Are you missing or exceeding some indexes in there??

Comment: Also there is an $ili$ symbol.. what is that!.....

Comment: $k$ is the commodity. so we have $K$ commodity of vehicles
I edited typos, thanks @hyprfrco

Comment: Ok if you have to decide between 0 and 1, you are no longer linear, you are discrete, do you know that, right?

Comment: I think you should think on that, because, it is part of your assignment to figure out how to evaluate a problem. I could tell you but i am limiting you in not helping you develop that intuition behind.

Comment: Actually, you have to interpret each constraint, and see what they mean on a real problem. Try it with R2 and you will catch it immediately. It is reduced to do a domain search.